# yii query builder sorts by default

Tags: php, yii

I created a query:

```
<?php

$conditions = array();
$params = array();

$ids = explode(',', $_GET['ids']);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ids); $i++)
{
    $conditions[] = 'ID=:id'.$i;
    $params[':id'.$i] = $ids[$i];
}            

if (!empty($conditions)) $conditions=implode(' OR ', $conditions);

$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
               ->select()
               ->from('ABC')
               ->where($conditions, $params)
               ->limit(sizeof($ids))
               ->queryAll();

print_r($query);
```

problem is, by default it sorts the results by my table's primary key

my url looks like this, `localhost/view?ids=6,5,1,4`

and the results are sorted `1,4,5,6` i don't want that. is there a way not to sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always set order to `DESC` to make order descending or it will sort by defaults

```
->order('col_name desc')
```

also you can add a where with `in` condition to avoid that loop for creating where part

```
->where(array('in' , 'col_name' , $id_array))
```

Comment: but using the IN clause how do i use `$params` to prevent mysql injections?? coz the array of id's are taken from url

Comment: make a loop and cast every id to `int`, like : `$id_array[] = (int) $id` to protect yourself